# Referencing a downstream class in type hinting for a class method

Tags: python, class, methods, types, pycharm

I am building a python game using pygame. Struggling a bit to add typing to things. I have a abstract group class Mobs which I define with:

```
class Mobs(pygame.sprite.Group):
```

I then create individual monsters with:

```
class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
```

Later in the file. The trouble I'm running into is in creating a method `render_image` of `Mobs` which I'm trying to add type hinting to.

```
def render_image(self, sprite: Mob) -> tuple[Surface, Rect]:
```

I get the following error:

[image: error message: Unresolved reference]

It seems the reason the reference is unresolved is because the class `Mob` gets created further down in the file. Is there a way I can fix this and add type hinting the way I'm trying to?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple answer is to add to the top of your module:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

# rest of module
...
```

This "stringifies" your annotations, so that the processing of them is delayed until some bit of code asks about them. Which, in the course of most programs, is never. Most annotations are only ever used by static analysis tools (like mypy), which do not actually run the code. Most (all?) static analysis tools know to eval string annotations as this has been the standardised way of doing forward references for some time.

`from __future__ import annotations` doesn't do anything very complicated. And you can reproduce the behaviour yourself by enclosing the annotations in quote marks. These two modules are equivalent:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo:
    def f(self, bar: Bar) -> None:
        ...

class Bar:
    def g(self, foo: Foo) -> None:
        ...
```

Doing the stringification manually:

```py
class Foo:
    def f(self, bar: 'Bar') -> 'None':
        ...

class Bar:
    def g(self, foo: 'Foo') -> 'None':
        ...
```

If you need to get the actual types back then you can use [`inspect.get_annotations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.get_annotations), which is available from python 3.10. For earlier versions you will need to manually `eval()` the strings yourself (see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html#manually-un-stringizing-stringized-annotations )